# How to fit image in a circle icon in html/css?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I want to fit the image in a circle icon `width:64px;height:64px`
But I am not able to do that.

1. My Image is showing full and in a frame(`width:64px;height:64px`)
2. Image is not shrinking
3. But not showing in a circle

What I am trying is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/soniya_jain/esu413wv/5/

I am also posting code here:

```
<html>
 <img src="https://www.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Apple-ios-13-home-screen-iphone-xs-06032019.jpg" class="rounded imgProfile" height="55px" width="55px" alt="avatar">
</html>


 <style>
   .imgProfile {
     display: block;
     object-fit: contain;
    }
 </style>
```

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap it into a container.

```css
.image-container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Apple-ios-13-home-screen-iphone-xs-06032019.jpg" alt="avatar">
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Kindly pass this url the image will be shrink https://www.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Apple-ios-13-home-screen-iphone-xs-06032019.jpg

Comment: either use object-fit either crop your image

Comment: I am using object-fit:contain;   kindly check: https://jsfiddle.net/soniya_jain/esu413wv/5/

Comment: I added object fit: cover in my answer